# Custom Xamarin Picker

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, picker

Just wondering how I may implement a basic custom picker in Xamarin.Forms. I have never made a custom control so am not too experienced with the process.

All I wish to do is to add another option at the bottom of the Picker aside from the existing "Cancel" option. This new option (is it a button ?) will sit at the bottom left hand side of the picker. It sounds like it should be easy enough.

Thanks in advance for any tips or guidance.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22961/custom-xaml-component-in-xamarin-forms

Here's a tutorial for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at this [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amporis.Xamarin.Forms.ColorPicker/) nuget package if you want to use one that's already been created?
The docs and samples can be found [here](https://github.com/PetrVobornik/ColorPicker)